# AirflowException("Task received SIGTERM signal")

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm running Airflow with Docker swarm on 5 servers. After using 2 months, there are some errors on Dags like this. These errors occurred in dags that using a custom hive operator (similar to the inner function ) and no error occurred before 2 months. (Nothing changed with Dags...)

Also, if I tried to retry dag, sometimes it succeeded and sometimes it failed.

The really weird thing about this issue is that hive job was not failed. After the task was marked as failed in the airflow webserver (Sigterm), the query was complete after 1~10 mins.

As a result, flow is like this.

- Task start -> 5~10 mins -> error (sigterm, airflow) -> 1~10 mins -> hive job success (hadoop log)

```
[2023-01-09 08:06:07,583] {local_task_job.py:208} WARNING - State of this instance has been externally set to up_for_retry. Terminating instance.
[2023-01-09 08:06:07,588] {process_utils.py:100} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 135213
[2023-01-09 08:06:07,588] {taskinstance.py:1236} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2023-01-09 08:13:42,510] {taskinstance.py:1463} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/common/operator/hive_q_operator.py", line 81, in execute
    cur.execute(statement)  # hive query custom operator
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 454, in execute
    response = self._connection.client.ExecuteStatement(req)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/TCLIService/TCLIService.py", line 280, in ExecuteStatement
    return self.recv_ExecuteStatement()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/TCLIService/TCLIService.py", line 292, in recv_ExecuteStatement
    (fname, mtype, rseqid) = iprot.readMessageBegin()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py", line 134, in readMessageBegin
    sz = self.readI32()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py", line 217, in readI32
    buff = self.trans.readAll(4)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 62, in readAll
    chunk = self.read(sz - have)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thrift_sasl/__init__.py", line 173, in read
    self._read_frame()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thrift_sasl/__init__.py", line 177, in _read_frame
    header = self._trans_read_all(4)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thrift_sasl/__init__.py", line 210, in _trans_read_all
    return read_all(sz)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 62, in readAll
    chunk = self.read(sz - have)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 150, in read
    buff = self.handle.recv(sz)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1238, in signal_handler
    raise AirflowException("Task received SIGTERM signal")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Task received SIGTERM signal
```

I already restarted the airflow server and there was nothing changed.

Here is the failed task's log (flower log)

Is there any helpful guide for me?

Thanks :)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 412, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 704, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 88, in execute_command
    _execute_in_fork(command_to_exec)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 99, in _execute_in_fork
    raise AirflowException('Celery command failed on host: ' + get_hostname())
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Celery command failed on host: 8be4caa25d17
```

Comment: SIGTERM is an indication that the task doesn't get enough resources to complete the process and is erroring out in the middle.

Comment: @BhavaniRavi Thanks. Can I get more specific information about resources ? Is it local server's resources (RAM or CPU or else...) or containers resources ?

Comment: Wherever you are getting this error. The worker containers are getting killed